# Why commenting/uncommenting alert() in constructor toggles variable as part of the obj instances

Tags: javascript, tostring

In the following code, if I comment `//alert("Your Name is: " +fname);` in the constructor function then 'alert(p1.fname);`alerts "Suresh" and If I remove the comment out the`alert("Your Name is: " +fname);`then browser console gives out the error`: fname is not defined`

```
function person () {
    this.fname = "Suresh";
    alert("Your Name is: " +fname);
  }

  var p1 = new person();

  alert(p1.fname);
```

I am puzzled by this behaviour. Pls explain

thanks

Comment: try: `alert("Your Name is: " + this.fname);`

Comment: Yes. that works. Just plain oversight  though I could not downvote this myself. I doubted my basic understanding of JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a variable that doesn't exist in the first `alert()`, so get you an error message telling you the variable is not defined`

There is no variable named `fname` inside the `person()` function, it's called `this.fname`, just like you created it

```
function person () {
    this.fname = "Suresh";
    alert("Your Name is: " + this.fname);
  }

  var p1 = new person();

  alert(p1.fname);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/e11ubcqp/)

Comment: Oh. That was just plain oversight. Thanks for bringing it to my attention.