# Why accessing property on a function object gives undefined?

Tags: javascript, object

The function object `Foo` when accessing it property `x` using `this` operator gives `undefined`. Why ?

```
function Foo(){ 
        this.x = "bar";
        return this;
    }

console.log(Foo.x); //undefined
```

I believe declaring a function JS automatically creates a function object to which you can add properties. For e.g this works:

```
Foo.today = "Sunday";
console.log(Foo.today); // Sunday
```

Comment: In [one of your own questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34290132/why-commenting-uncommenting-alert-in-constructor-toggles-variable-as-part-of-t) from very recently, you posted similar code but different expectations of what would happen.

Answer (score 1):

Functions are objects. You're adding an "x" property to whatever `this` refers to when the function `Foo()` is called, but nothing in your code calls it.

If you were to call the function like this:

```
Foo.call(Foo);
```

before checking the value of `Foo.x`, it would work. Generally, however, the value of `this` in a function call is *not* a reference to the function itself.

You can also do:

```
Foo.x = "bar";
```

*Usually*, assigning properties to `this` in a function, especially one used as a constructor, is done to manage properties of objects (objects that are *not* the function itself).  So:

```
var f = new Foo();
```

will give you an object with a property named "x" and value "bar".

Answer (score 0):

Just delete `return this;` and use `var f = new Foo()`. Then `console.log(f.x)` will work.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking on non "strict" mode, in the context you used it, `this` keywords defaults to the global object since it is not yet set by a call to the function itself. So you simply set a `x` property on the `window` Object.

Comment: What `this` defaults to in `Foo` is irrelevant is this code, as it's not calling the function `Foo` anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Calling Foo.x will return `'undefined'` as x is an instance(object) property not a function property(`Foo.x = "bar"`). Declare x as a class(function) property `Foo.x = "bar";` than call it in `console.log(Foo.x)`.

In this case `x` is an instance property (`this.x ='bar'`) not a class(`function`) property(as `Foo.x='bar'`) to get access to `Foo.x`,`Foo` has to be instantiated "`var foo = new Foo()`" than calling `foo.x` is returning `Foo's` instance property of `x`.